# Cannot count elements in a column created with string.split which is supposed to be a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a pandas df with info about netflix shows. One of the columns was a string with all the countries involved in the production `netflix_df['country']`. I created an additional column which is intended to be a list of all the individual countries (because there are coproductions involving more than one country) called `netflix_df['list_of_countries']` by using the following code:

```
netflix_df['list_of_countries']=netflix_df['country'].str.split(',')
```

Afterwards, I attempted to create a new column called `netflix_df['number_of_countries']` which included the number of countries in the lists of the column `netflix_df[list_of_countries]` by doing the following:

```
netflix_df['number_of_countries'] = [len(c) for c in netflix_df['list_of_countries']]
```

Nevertheless, I got the following error: TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

This doesn't make sense to me, since the column is filled with lists and not floats. What is wrong in my code? I would appreciate some help with this. Thank you very much.

Comment: is `c` an iterable? It seems not, the type error says that you trying to get the length of a float, if `netflix_df['list_of_countries']` is an actual python list you should do `len(netflix_df['list_of_countries'])`

Comment: Did you perform any processing on `netflix_df['list_of_countries']`? `nan` is type `float` in pandas and numpy. If you filled `nan` for empty list then you might have this error

Comment: That would be my guess too as @RaghavaDhanya, missing values  are sometimes interpreted as float

Comment: Yes,  @RaghavaDhanyait is an issue of that sort. It interpreted Nan as a float. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can get `len` of each list like below:

```
netflix_df['number_of_countries'] = netflix_df['list_of_countries'].apply(len)
```